# In clear terms what is an ArrayList and how to use it?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

If I look up what an ArrayList is and how to use it I often get confused. I get scared when I look at this for example:

```
new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(array))
```

I probably have a few gaps in my understanding of ArrayLists as a beginner. For example: What does `<>` stand for? Does it have special meaning? How is it internally represented? (For example: I see variables as representing a place in memory, array variables as a starting position in memory and an index of an array as a way to say how much further to go from this starting position.)

**An example of where I think I need an ArrayList:**
*(I was trying to create an array of integers of user-input. The user-input is one integer at a time, the end condition is when the user inputs a zero `endSign = 0`.)* Since Java doesn't allow re-sizing of an array after its creation, I searched for a solution to create an array of a dynamic length. ArrayList seems to be an option if I convert it to an array at the end, if I understand that correctly? If that's the case than it would be probably useful to make use of an ArrayList here:

```
    private int[] userInput(int endSign){ //end-sign is 0 in this case
    int validInputCounter=0;
    List<int> userValues;
    int value;
    do{
        value = readInt(); //reads integer user-input
        if(value != endSign){ 
            validInputCounter++;
            userValues += value;  
        }else{
        break;
        }
    }while(true);
    return userValues;  
}
```

In this code I want to return an int[] array of values that the user put in.

Comment: You can find all your answers on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html . You cannot do  List<int> userValues; have you tired anything ? You have to use generics like  List<Integer> userValues;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to familiarize yourself with the Stack Overflow [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help), which will help you understand what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site. This site is intended to help you obtain answers to *specific programming questions*, as opposed to providing tutorial, design or code review assistance. Read the Java Tutorials on List implementations and separately, on Generics. Use Google to find the tutorial.

Comment: <> is mainly to do with "Template"ing your classes. This is very object-oriented and generic approach. This is also available in C++ the idea is that you keep your types flexible and the types get assigned during compile time. All the compiler needs to know is how the templates should be implemented i.e. the definitions of the template classes/functions.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I really did my best to make this an appropriate question and to find the solution myself. I have never heard of Collections and Generics, Maps and many more. Everything I read just made me more confused. Now I got a lead into the forest about the important subjects. The reason I asked this question was because of a specific programming problem, which I included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<>` are the *type arguments*. They are for you to **specify what type of objects will be stored in that list**. You cannot use primitive types as type-arguments. You can only store objects in lists, nost primitives. Check out [The Java Tutorials - Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

An `ArrayList` is a `Collection`, and there are other types of collections (such as `LinkedList` and some synchronized collections. You can read about collections at [The Java Tutorials - Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)). You can look into each one individually to see where they excel. There are also [Maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html), which you should look in to. They also dynamically grow in size, but instead of storing single objects, they store a key/pair value.

You got the main idea right: arrays dont change in size. `List`s dynamically grow in size when needed.

Example of ArrayList in use:

```
class Demo {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
          ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

          intList.add(1);
          intList.add("s"); //error

          stringList.add("s");
          stringList.add(2); //error
     }
}
```

I suggest reading [The Java Tutorials - Autoboxing and Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), since you cannot use primitive types as type arguments. The primitive 1 we added to the intList will be boxed into an object, since the list takes `Integer` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the online Java Tutorial? You have a few different questions here relating to Collections and Generics (the <> syntax), so take a look here first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

And specifically,
for Collections: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html
and for Generics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html

Answer (score 1):

A few things that might help:

1. `ArrayList<Element>` refers to an `ArrayList` of `Element` data types. That means, each item on the list is a type of `Element` (an instance of the Element class of interface). The tags were introduced in Java 5 and are referred to as generics. This is a mechanism to resolve at compile-time compatibility of data types, instead of waiting until you run the code and figure out you have some sort of problem (i.e. ClassCastException). There is no advantages of using generics at runtime.
2. You can use `userValues.toArray()` to return an array instead of a `List`.
3. A List of ints is not allowed.  You have to use the wrapper class `Integer` instead. With Java unboxing mechanism, an `Integer` is automatically converted to a primitive `int`. Autoboxing is the opposite: is the process of converting a primitive to its wrapper class equivalent; in this case from `int` to `Integer`.
4. Yes, if you are not sure what size you need your array to be, you can use an `ArrayList` and call the `toArray()` method and return the array equivalent as stated in item #2 above.